# What is the difference between the fingerprint and v3ident in auth_dirs.c

Tags: security, directory

auth_dirs contains a list of trusted directory authorities and consists of entrys such:

```
"moria1 orport=9101 "
  "v3ident=D586D18309DED4CD6D57C18FDB97EFA96D330566 "
  "128.31.0.39:9131 9695 DFC3 5FFE B861 329B 9F1A B04C 4639 7020 CE31",
```

What is the difference between the v3ident and the fingerprint in the line with the url and OR?

From my understanding, the v3ident is compared to the SHA1 Hash of the public Authority Identity Key of the key certificate.

What is the other one used for?